# Плавное присвоение атрибута

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg

Использую плагин [LazyLinePainter](https://github.com/camoconnell/lazy-line-painter) для рисования контуров SVG. Но проблема в том, что плагин рисует только линии, но не делает заливку по окончанию процесса рисования. По сему, я решил допилить заливку самостоятельно, но заливка появляется резко, а я бы хотел сделать её плавной. Можно ли как-то плавно изменить значение атрибута?

```
'onStrokeStart':  function(){
    setTimeout(function(){
        $('#goodwin-logo svg path').attr({
            'fill': 'rgba(255,255,255, 0)',
            'fill-opacity': '1'
        });
        $('#goodwin-logo svg path').fadeIn("slow", function() {
            $(this).attr({
                'fill': 'rgba(255,255,255, 1)'
            })
        });
    }, 2500);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Разобрался самостоятельно, через css:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#goodwin-svg path').css({
        'transition': 'fill-opacity 2s ease 1.5s',
        'fill-opacity': '1'
    });
});
```